# Schur's Orthogonality relations

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups, measurable-functions, locally-compact-groups

I am trying to calculate the same question that got asked a few years back.

[Identities related to Schur's orthogonality relations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2691021/identities-related-to-schurs-orthogonality-relations)

But in the comments one guy gives a way to try and compute it with the polarization identity. But i get confused why he get $\frac{1}{8}$ out, when we writes that formula. I would think he got $\frac{1}{16}$ out instead?. And in the last expression the last terms isn't squared???

And why would it not be smart to write\begin{align*}
(u,u')\overline{(v,v')} = (u,u')(v',v)
\end{align*}
and then try and multiply the equation out?
\begin{align*}
(u,u')(v',v) = \frac{1}{16} \bigg( &\big( \|u+u'\|^2 - \|u-u'\|^2+i\|u+iu\|^2 - i\|u-iu\|^2 \big) \\
&\big( \|v'+v\|^2 - \|v'-v\|^2+i\|v'+iv\|^2 - i\|v'-iv\|^2
\big) \bigg) 
\end{align*}
But if i multiply all this out i dont seem to get anything "nice". Am i thinking this wrong, and any suggestions to reach the desired result would be appreciated :)

Comment: Indeed, $4 \times 4 = 16$. And once you have expanded, you can use the first identity of the linked question to get the second one.

Comment: I just don't see how i can use the first identity?? 
ex. for the first term i would get
$$ \| u + u'\|^2  \| v' - v\|^2  - \| u + u'\|^2  \| v' - v\|^2  + i \| u + u'\|^2  \| v' + iv\|^2 - i\| u + u'\|^2  \| v' - iv\|^2 
$$
What would i do from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let us focus on the first term. Multiplying out, we get
\begin{align*}\|u+u'\|^2
&\|v'+v\|^2 - \|u+u'\|^2\|v'-v\|^2\\+i \|u+u'\|^2&\|v'+iv\|^2 - i \|u+u'\|^2\|v'-iv\|^2\\
&=
\int_{G}\big(\vert\langle{\pi(g)(u+u’),v’+v}\rangle\vert^{2}-\vert\langle{\pi(g)(u+u’),v’-v}\rangle\vert^{2}\\&\quad+i \vert\langle{\pi(g)(u+u’),v’+iv}\rangle\vert^{2}-i \vert\langle{\pi(g)(u+u’),v’-iv}\rangle\vert^{2}\big)\, \mu(dg).
\end{align*}
Now, the expressions
$$
\vert\langle{\pi(g)u,v}\rangle\vert^{2}
$$
will have their own polarization identity, and so you can go back basically following the same way backwards.